# Sort Ecore classes topologically

Tags: sorting, hierarchy, eclipse-emf

Is there a way to perform topological sorting of the classes in an Ecore EPackage, i.e sort the list of classes so that classes that use another class as supertype are positioned after their superclass? I did something similar for another code generator using manual graph traversal, but surely someone must already have implemented this for Ecore.

Answer (score 0):

[MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/) allows to define queries on metamodels. So you can write a query for an Ecore model that returns the EClasses in topological order. This shouldn't be a to difficult task with such a query implemented in Java. See the [help for MoDisco](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gmt.modisco.infra.doc/doc/MoDisco/Components/QueryManager/Documentation/0.9/0.9.html) for more information.